# Maento Product get wrong URL on crosssell,upsell,and in search resulr list page

Tags: magento, url, product

Hi i have site in magento. it create duplicates URL after updgradation on cart,crossell,upsell and cart page. I tried many ways also do googling so much. but not get luck..
this is the case

Orginal URL

http://www.test.com/new/inner/myself-antena.html

New, duplicate URL for SKU: ZE-1925

http://www.test.com/catalog/product/view/id/4951/s/myself-antena.html

Can u please help me what i have to do for that?????

Comment: Going to at least see code from the template file(s) responsible.